# How to return rows which have not specific values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example: `df = df[df.Number = 1]`

I want to filter rows for a specific list of numbers. For example:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

I tried

```
df3 = df[df.Number == "01"or"02"]
```

Can I use a list after  `df3 = df[df.Number == __]` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 1):

`isin` is an efficient method of filtering according to numbers in a list:

```
import pandas as pd
df = df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Number":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
print(df[df.Number.isin([2,3])])
```

returns:

```
   Number
1       2
2       3
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should use a `for` loop, e.g.:

```py
df3 = [df[index] for index in (2, 3)]
```

This is equivalent to:

```py
df3 = [df[2], df[3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Filter df which is contains `1` or `2`:

```py
df[(df.Number == 1) | (df.Number == 2)] # output : 1, 2
```

Filter df which is not contains `1` and `2`:

```py
df[~((df.Number == 1) | (df.Number == 2))] # output : 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [.isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method is for.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, (5)), columns=['Number'])
df
```

```
   Number
0       0
1       0
2       2
3       2
4       0
```

```py
df[df.Number.isin([1,2])]
```

```
   Number
2       2
3       2
```

If you want to exclude the selection, you just need to invert the selection:

```py
df[~df.Number.isin([1,2])]
```

```
   Number
0       0
1       0
4       0
```